# Is there any way to change default pressed color for all listviews in android?

Tags: android, listview

The application I'm developing has several lists of items (including one in NavigationDrawer, one in a dialog, etc).

When the user press one item on the list on pre-lollipop smartphones, the background changes to a light blue color (including preferences on PreferenceActivity). On lollipop devices, however, the background changes to a light grey color with a beautiful ripple effect. What I want is to have the same light grey color for all devices (the ripple effect is not needed).

I've seem some posts of people styling ListView items setting backgrounds, but I need an approach to style all of them at once.

ps: my app uses Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar as base theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file res/drawable/listitem_background.xml with the following content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/purple_dark" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Replace the `@color/purple_dark` with the color of your choice.

Then, in your theme, add the following line :

```
<item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/listitem_background</item>
```

EDIT:

To mantain the lollipop effects and colors instead of placing the theme in the values folder, place it in the `values-v22`

Comment: this will also overwrite the lollypop animation for listviews.

Comment: android:activatedBackgroundIndicator and android:state_activated seems to be for api 11+. Is there anything similar that's compatible with api 8?

Comment: @Tinadm I don't think so, but also I don't  think you should take too much effort making compatibility with Froyo, according to google http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html , less than the 0,4% of the Android devices still having froyo, so I think supporting api 11 and above is enough.

Comment: @El_Mochiq yeah, I think you're right... supporting Honeycomb should be enough. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is it possible to make pre-Kitkat versions to have the same selector as of Kitkat, yet Lollipop+ versions to have their own native selector?

Comment: @androiddeveloper And that would be another question.

Answer (score 1):

Define a style resource file like this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/MyListViewStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyListViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.ListView">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <!-- Other stuff you need -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

In your manifest set

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

Now all of your ListView's will look like you define in style by default. You can of course change some of them if you want.

You can find a more complex, but very useful sample [HERE](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml)